# Removing AngularJS currency filter "," and replace with a space my data base doesnt allow special characters

Tags: angularjs

Removing AngularJS currency filter "," and replace with a space my data base doesnt allow special characters 
I get this R68,993.85
I want this R68 993.85

Comment: can you please  add your code? it will better to understand.

Comment: file:///home/thulani1/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202016-06-23%2010:13:48.png  Here is the code its working properly   but I dont want the comma to be displayed in my amount file:///home/thulani1/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202016-06-23%2010:13:17.jpg like this , is it possible to replace it with a space

Comment: what You have shared .I cant access image on your local.please share code .or add jsfiddle or plunker link .

Comment: as yougurt said. currency filter wont change you model in database.are you manually changing it??

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/pdTKDeOdTwa3ULf2z9Xr?p=preview Where my answer is displayed I dont want it to display the comma

Comment: it is "R12,234.60" right now.you want output as "R12234.60" like this? really?

Comment: you can achieve this simply by string .replace function posted in answer..check it out

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to replace it. `currency` is a filter, it just changes how the given value look. It won't modify your model value so you won't save the formatted number in your database. If you do, then you should check how you use this filter.

Answer (score 1):

your requirement is little weird .if you are using currency filter thern , should be there. but still if you have limitation that you cant change you database structure. then you can try this.

var str = "R12,234.60";
 var res = str.replace(","," ");